# Electrum server over http

Tags: electrum

Is it possible to communicate with an electrum server using http? I'm interested in building a browser extension.

I also see this message on the electrum chrome plugin

> Unfortunately, all public Electrum servers have upgraded to a version of the protocol this extension does not support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, new nodes don't support the HTTP transport. You'll need to use TCP.